# Terrible Review Audit Question - Looks Like Server Fault Question

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed this review audit in the reopen queue; https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/29079569

[image: Screenshot of Review Audit]

It looks to me to be about a question about a server of some kind and not coding. Maybe it isn't, but I saw no reason for it to be reopened. I chose for the question to remain closed, and obviously I failed the audit.

For me this seems like a horrendous review audit question. I don't care about the strike, but hope the question doesn't get used for someone else.

Comment: It looks on-topic for Stack Overflow. It's talking about a warning someone is getting in an IDE (namely xCode). That doesn't seem off-topic to me. In terms of the audit... meh. It's not that bad, but it's not that good either.

Comment: That is absolutely not a Server Fault question.  It's absolutely not about server or network administration, especially in professional setting.  The question was a big vague since it put the error message in the title, but given it is about upgrading xcode, i don't see why it isn't on-topc on SO.  PSA:  there is no shame in clicking the Skip button

Comment: I would have voted to close the question because it says "I'm getting this warning" yet there's no reference to what the warning means...

Comment: @Braiam The warning is the title of the question (not optimal, but an easy fix)

Comment: I'm not disputing the question itself, I'm saying that it's a poor review audit question. It really doesn't look like a question that should obviously be reopened.

Comment: The only way I could see this being confused for a Server Fault question is if you don't know what Xcode is, and if you don't know what the question is talking about enough to judge whether it's on topic you should probably just skip it.

Comment: @RyanM ugh, the different layout on review vs the actual site makes me gloss over all the information on the top. #bringbackoldreviewlayout

Comment: “I'm saying that it's a poor review audit question.” - It actually is the perfect audit question, one where you will only fail the audit, when your not paying attention.  You failed to check if the question was really closed.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to be familiar with every technology out there, so tags are your friends. The first line of the tag wiki for Xcode:

> Xcode is Apple's integrated development environment (IDE).

This tells you that Xcode is on topic as a [tool primarily (if not exclusively) used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Checking the other tags will tell you what type of programming (Swift targeting iOS).

From the tags alone, it should be clear that it isn't better suited to another site. It's not asking for a library, it's not a typo question (since the code was working before the update) and it's probably not helpful to ask for code (again, because their project was working before the update and is probably too large to be helpful). All signs are pointing to the question being OK, though you may want to either skip or look at the answer to see if it was able to solve the problem with only the context given.